# resend.com status code 200 & delivered log but does not arrive in mailbox

Tags: next.js, resend.com

I'm having a problem with sending mails via resend with a react body. When i send my mails with a text body i get status 200, the log says that it is delivered and i can see the mail in my mailbox. When i send an email with a react body the first two just work fine but i dont get the email in my mailbox (i have looked in my spam folder.

**route.ts**

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { EmailTemplate } from '../../components/emailTemplate';
import { Resend } from 'resend';
import { getSession } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
import * as React from 'react';


const resend = new Resend(process.env.RESEND_API_KEY);

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  // get email info
  const { body } = request;
  // decode body
  let passedValue = await new NextResponse(body).text();
  let valueToJson = JSON.parse(passedValue);
  const { email } = valueToJson;
  console.log(email);

  // get current user
  const session = await getSession();
  const user = session?.user;

  // try to send email
  try {
    console.log("in try");
    const data = await resend.emails.send({
      from: 'Stage <no-reply@ourdomain.be>',
      to: ['myemail@myemail.be'],
      subject: 'Uitnodiging Energy!',
      // text: 'text',
      react: EmailTemplate({ firstName: 'John' }) as React.ReactElement,
      // react: EmailTemplate({ email:email, companyId:'clte87w710003glwww0slvgvp', username:user?.given_name }),
    });
    console.log(data);
    return Response.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return Response.json({ error });
  }
}
```

**emailTemplate.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';


interface EmailTemplateProps {
  firstName: string;
}

export const EmailTemplate: React.FC<Readonly<EmailTemplateProps>> = ({
  firstName,
}) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome, {firstName}!</h1>
  </div>
);

export default EmailTemplate;
```

**Resend version: ** ^3.2.0

I have looked for solutions online but unfortunately there is not many to find. I also tried to send a mail with a html body but that also doesn't work.

Comment: Meanwhile, it appears that the email on the mail server is blocked as span because we have not purchased our own ip address. Since it is blocked on the mail server, I also could not see the email in my spam folder.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, it appears that the email on the mail server is blocked as span because we have not purchased our own ip address. Since it is blocked on the mail server, I also could not see the email in my spam folder.